# How to take Amazon RDS postgresql dump if not publicly accessible

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS RDS. I have my db in amazon rds postgresql. I want to take dump of the database but my database in not publicly accessible.  Can anyone help me to take dump

Comment: It would be great if you can provide steps, article, or any video link

Comment: What do you want to do with this "dump"? Is it just for backup purposes, or are you wanting to load the data in a different database server. Please Edit your question to provide more information rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.